# Constrained (Bounded) Kalman filter in state vector

Tags: python, r, constraints, kalman-filter, state-space

Is there any R or Python package that allows to use the Kalman filter by imposing constraints on the state vector? More specifically:

- Kalman Filter

[image: Kalman Filter]

I want:

- Constraints

[image: Constraints]

I found R's MARSS library but I don't think it allows to enforce these constraints.